# Fixed Column Text overlaps with non-fixed column text when a HScroll scrolls past column border

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular

In the image below you can se that the text overlaps when a column with a "fixedLeft" property gets scrolled past. In this case scrolling to the right will trigger a text overflow when the second column surpasses the right border of the "fixed left column". Any ideas on what is causing this?

(It appears to have something to do with rowAlternationEnabled. The rows styled light gray do not show the overlapping text, while the alternate rows styled white do overlap)

[image]

Grid Configuration:

```
  <dx-data-grid class="list-page-data-grid"
    [class.hideHeader]="!dataLoaded"
    #DataGrid
    [dataSource]="gridData"
    keyExpr="OID"
    [allowColumnReordering]="true"
    [rowAlternationEnabled]="true"
    [showBorders]="false"
    [showColumnLines]="false"
    [allowColumnResizing]="true"
    columnResizingMode="widget"
    [columnAutoWidth]="true"
    [height]="'100%'"
    [hoverStateEnabled]="true"
    (onRowClick)="gridRowClick($event)"
    (onCellClick)="gridCellClick($event)"
    [visible]="!showMap"
    [filterSyncEnabled]="true"
    [customizeColumns]="customizeColumns"
    [wordWrapEnabled]="true"
    [width]="'100%'"
    [columnMinWidth]="32"
  >
    <dxo-column-fixing [enabled]="true"
    ></dxo-column-fixing>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked.

```
.dx-datagrid .dx-data-row:not(.dx-row-alt) > td {
    background-color: $white;
}
```